# Browser component for Java or C#

Tags: c#, java, browser

Is there any web browser component for Java or C# that supports JavaScript and can detect when a page fully loaded?
(When the page and its images are loaded, and the ajax requests are complete.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, check out the Elicpse SWT browser widget

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/

But keep in mind that "when AJAX requests are complete" is not a trivial issue.  If actions once the page is "loaded" cause additional async DOM modifications, then when is it "finally loaded" becomes an issue.

Comment: I would like to do something like to run a Java or C# function when the JavasScript `window.onload` function would be called.

Comment: Check the SWT docs to see if you can intercept that event via its Listener hierarchy; if you can, then you can certainly do that.  If not, another route is an alternative to SWT (but same kind of widget) or you can also look at writing an extension for something like Firefox. (not sure that's possible in your scenario, but it is an option)

Answer (score 1):

C# has the `WebBrowser` class which actually just is the IE that is installed on your computer. It's quite rich in functionality and has many methods. Perhaps it is enough for your goal. Certainly IE can do javascript and "knows" when Ajax calls are finished.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx